# Authentication to Sharepoint Online with CSOM more than one Context

Tags: csom

In my desktop application based on .NET Framework 4.8, I have to change the context to another site.

When I call it the first time it works perfect, but the another time I get an empty Login window and it stops at GetWebLoginClientContext()

```csharp
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl);
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```